# Get IP of remote client sending to socket

Tags: .net, sockets, asynchronous, network-programming, udp

How can I get the IP of the sending remote client when using the .NET `Socket` class with `BeginReceive` and `EndReceive`? I'm only able to retrieve the sent data, but not the IP address of the sending client.

Pseudo code sample shortened and without error handling for brevity:

```
this.Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
this.Socket.Bind(localAddress);

this.Socket.BeginReceive(
    buffer,
    0,
    buffer.Length,
    SocketFlags.None,
    this.OnSocketDataReceived,
    null
);

protected override void OnSocketDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
    SocketError socketError
    this.Socket.EndReceive(asyn, out socketError);
    // buffer contains data
    // how do I get the IP of the sending client?
}
```

Comment: Yes, it runs. It's using UDP (connectionless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use BeginReceiveFrom and EndReceiveFrom, as these allow you to pass in a reference to an EndPoint, like this:

```
IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
EndPoint senderRemote = (EndPoint)sender;
this.Socket.EndReceiveFrom(asyn, ref senderRemote);
```

From the endpoint, you can then get the IP address of the sending client.

Comment: This feels a bit wrong (especially casting back `EndPoint` to `IPEndPoint`), but it seems to be the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: You don't have to cast back, you can use the original IPEndPoint, as in the above example sender and senderRemote point to the same object.

Comment: if senderRemote is set inside EndReceiveFrom (after all, it's passed by-`ref`), then sender and senderRemote will reference two distinct objects. For all we know from the method definition, senderRemote might not even be an instance of `IPEndPoint` after being assigned inside `EndReceiveFrom`.

Comment: You're right. I just made a quick test app. If the internal implementation of EndReceiveFrom casts the passed senderRemote as an IPEndPoint and modifies is, the original IPEndPoint (sender) will reflect the changes. It could however re-instantiate it in which case you would need to cast back as you say.